# How can I change bundle Identifier in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode9.3

In older versions of Xcode you could click on settings and under General tab you can see your bundle identifier and change it, but in Xcode 9.3 everything is scattered you can't see where you can edit your bundle identifier. How do I locate my bundle identifier and edit it?

Comment: Did you look in the “General” tab of the *target* settings?

Comment: @MartinR I can't find even the word General on any of the tabs. All I see is Basic, Customized, All Combined, levels

Comment: Then you are on the “Build settings” tab, not on “General”

Comment: @MartinR tnx I had to change from projects to targets before I could see it